# How to determine the CPU type of a .dll file by .NET compact framework?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I need to be able to lookup the type of CPU for which a native .dll file is intended. When the CPU type is same as the CPU on which my application is running, my application will use the .dll files to do some operations. I would like to do this task using .Net Compact Framework.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you need... dlls created for compact framework are always CPU-independent. Are you talking about native dlls?

Comment: It's about native dlls. I should first check the CPU type of the native dlls. If it's not what i need I will not use it.I want to do the check in Compact Framework.

Comment: On might ask why you're deploying DLLs for the wrong processor in the first place....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the dll file as a binary stream and interpret it. The format of a dll is PE - Portable Executable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119 and somewhere here the CPU type is specified. I've google it a little and I've found something that you could use as an example: http://wiki.tcl.tk/9351